# Using an array as sorting relation to sort a different array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort elements in an array '$to_sort'  with regards to how these elements are sorted in a different array '$sorting_order'.

However, I don't know how to handle the case when the two arrays contain different elements.

```
$sorting_order[]=[introduction,skills,education,experience]
$to_sort[]=[experience,skills,education]
```

This is the desired result:

```
$sorted[]=[skills,education,experience]
```

**SOLUTION:
i got this solution that is,

```
$sorted = array_intersect($sorting_order, $to_sort);
print_r($sorted);
```

**

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it this way:

1) flip `a` around using `array_flip()`; this will create a map with the string values as the key and an ordinal value as the value.

2) use the map from 1) in `usort()`.

```
$amap = array_flip($a);
usort($b, function($str1, $str2) use ($amap) {
    $key1 = $amap[$str1]; // decide what to do if the key doesn't exist
    $key2 = $amap[$str2];

    if ($key1 > $key2) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($key1 == $key2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
});
```

Comment: it would in that condotion also if array size is different as i mentioned ??